# problems in adobe flash player for firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, freeze, adobe

Is there a version of flash that doesnt crash or freeze my computer? If there isn't anything like that, is there any other software that works like flash and works on things that require flash (like videos online) but has less glitches, or a software that keeps flash stable and less problematic? If so, please let me know with an answer. BTW,I was wondering if gnash is helpful at all?

Comment: i also want to know whether these problems are version-specific

Comment: Tell us what version of flash you are using, and what computer you are using. Also, what version of ubuntu. Please provide some more info so the community can help you.

Comment: Just use the offical Google Chrome.  It comes bundled with Flash out of the box and works perfectly.

Comment: in the ubuntu software center, the first result that appears when you type flash is the flash that i installed.